# Difference between ways of sharing dashboard in power bi report server(on-premises) like embed or api or url access or wmi provider or report viewer

Tags: rest, wmi, embedding, power-bi-report-server, urlaccess

i write an web application for wrapping power bi report server web portal(on-premises),my users have access to folders or category items(all of kind such data source) without seen the web portal and they see my user interface.
i want to integrated dashboard in my ui. the simple way is embed by adding "?rs:embed=true" to end of url of that report url.
our database are so huge and full of data(average 5 million rows for each table) and when i embedded it this may take a time for rendering.
i wanna  better way to integrated my dashboard or report or kpi with best time to rendering.
we have few solution for this like urlaccess or wmi provider or report view control or rest api.which one is better? and have more less time of loading reports?
can i simulate a backend system(or client side) like report viewer control  for viewing reports directly?
can you show me link for .net core example(code) of this work or like this work?
thanks alot
mohammadreza daneshvar

Answer (score 0):

You can write an intermediate program and the customer can communicate with the Power BI server By your own API. so you can define your access level and customization your dashboard. this way is fast and easy